# JQuery DataTables.net custom column width doesn't work after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a problem with a jQuery datatable. As you can see from this definition, the data source of the table is an ajax call. Everything runs fine and the data shows but the column widths are not respected. When the table displays, the two columns are given more or less equal widths. I have attached a screen shot to show the behavior. When I resize the dialog even a little bit, everything snaps into place.

Here's the table HTML and the DataTables() call:

```
<table id="tblNotes" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="80px">Date</th>
        <th width="500px">Note</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

And the datatables call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tblNotes").DataTable({
        "ajax" : {
            "url": "/projects/ajaxGetProjectNotes/",
            "type" : "post",
            "dataType" : "json",
            "data" : function(d){
                return {
                    idProject : $("#pn-idProject").val()
                };
            }
        },
        "columns" : 
        [
            {"data" : "dComment", "width" : "80px", "orderable" : true},
            {"data" : "cComment", "width" : "500px", "orderable" : false}
        ]
    });
```

The datatable is in a jQueryUI Dialog. Here's what it looks like when first displayed:

[image: When it starts]

[image: When resized]

Comment: Could, you by chance, add some code?  I would think you could simply set the column width's afterward, but without code I can't directly give you a solution.

Comment: Sorry. I hit enter during the post and it saved. My bad. I was editing it to add the code when you commented. I am also trying to get some screen shots to show... didn't work so I will edit it again.

edit: I can't seem to get the images to show. Here are the links:

Comment: I couldn't get the images to show so here they are as links (I hope this works)

[when it loads](http://imgur.com/ExkzIAc)

[after a resize](http://imgur.com/lMcm0t5)

Comment: Hey, one last thing, could I also get the json file returned (or a section of it)?

Comment: `{"data":[{"id":"d2e0b49c-3ab0-4376-a337-ac3c720594a0","idProject":"b92792db-9ea6-49bf-b4dc-1cdf3f441148"
,"dComment":"03\/08\/2017","cComment":"Spoke to the vendor. I wondered just what they were smoking. Turns
 out they were right and I was wrong. Oh well. Better luck next time.","tLastUpdated":"2017-03-08 13
:44:33","cUpdatedFrom":null},{"id":"721b50b5-9f10-4761-aef4-b5d7c31c21a5","idProject":"b92792db-9ea6-49bf-b4dc-1cdf3f441148"
,"dComment":"03\/07\/2017","cComment":"Another test note to see how this all works.","tLastUpdated":"2017-03-08
 16:12:40","cUpdatedFrom":null}]}`

Comment: Fixed it, used some css styling.  Thank you very much for your patients while I worked on it.  If you could please mark it as a solution then upvote it, it would help a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how DataTables is implemented, you can set the width for all columns but one. That column is then designed to take up the rest of the space.

However, we don't want that. So, what I did was put a new entry into the CSS portion of the file.

I added:

```
table#tblNotes {
    max-width:580px;
}
```

This makes it so that the width will not exceed 580px for the entire table. I got that number by adding your two columns width's together (80px + 500px). I then removed your width code under "note".  And now it works perfectly.

```
<style>

table#tblNotes {
    max-width:580px;
}

</style>

<div class="container">
    <table id="tblNotes" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="80px">Date</th>
            <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tblNotes").DataTable({
        "ajax" : {
            "url": "test.json",
            "type" : "post",
            "dataType" : "json",
            "data" : function(d){
                return {
                    idProject : $("#pn-idProject").val()
                };
            }
        },
        "columns" : 
        [
            {"data" : "dComment", "width" : "80px", "orderable" : true},
            {"data" : "cComment", "width" : "500px", "orderable" : false}
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That worked. Ran into a different issue though. I had to add a scroller effect to the table and now the longer text is not wrapping in the columns. Should I put that in as a separate question? (I'm kind of new to stackoverflow).

Comment: You should probably make a separate question (in case I am ill-prepared to fix it). Additionally, can I see the new code by chance?  Just post it in the new question when you post.